# "http-proxy-middleware" does not work in production mode. (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, proxy, http-proxy-middleware

**my setupProxy.js**

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware(`/API`, {
      target: "https://dev-api.id.com",
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        "^/API": "",
      },
    })
  );
};
```

**in localhost**

```
const data = await axios.get('/API/user')...     
browser send request url ==> 'https://dev-api.id.com/user'
```

i get status code 200

**in amazon s3 production**

```
const data = await axios.get('/API/user')...
browser send request url ==> https://my_amazon_url.com/API/user
```

i want to request to `https://dev-api.id.com/user` like "localhost"

but production mode send request to `https://my_amazon_url.com/API/user`

because my request url doesn't chage. so i get status code 404.

how can i solve this problem?